# Problems running programs installed in docker platform containers

Tags: linux, bash, docker, dockerfile, containers

I rented a docker platform container and tried to run it using a `Dockerfile` with the following code:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN cd /tmp

RUN apt update

RUN apt full-upgrade -y

RUN apt install wget libglib2.0-0 netbase -y
RUN wget https://(sample download link for the program to be installed).deb
RUN dpkg -i /tmp/(example program).deb
CMD /opt/my program/my program
```

However in running pods I get log information like this:

```
This Program requires root privileges
```

When I try to install it in Workdir root with example docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

WORKDIR /root
RUN cd /root
RUN apt update
RUN apt full-upgrade -y
RUN apt install wget libglib2.0-0 netbase -y
RUN wget https://(sample download link for the program to be installed).deb

RUN dpkg -i /tmp/(example program).deb
RUN chmod +x /root/my program

CMD /root/My Programs
```

The result I got was:

```
/bin/bash My program Permisson denied
```

tried to change CMD to add to:

```
CMD["bash", "/root/myprogram"]
```

The result is still

```
/bash My program Permisson denied
```

I wrapped the above code using dockerfile.

Comment: As you've shown it, both Dockerfiles do run as root.  How are you launching the container?  Can you more concretely say what the program inside the container actually is; is it something you wrote yourself?  (The variations in spacing and capitalization across the examples can cause real problems.)

Comment: I rented a cloud service provider who to build a container just need to copy and paste the dockerfile which was already made on github by me before , this is an application that i usually run on docker using a personal computer, but when i try to run it on this cloud service provider i have the above problem